# upload my sql database into my html form using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need some help with this project. I've gone as far as I can go, with no results, The inquiry form works, but I need to populate it with my sql table. I could only screen shot my sql and I have no idea of how to put it on here. The following is the scenerio: Uploading Information Directly into the Inquiry Table

In this scenario I will be using the inquiry form that I created in one of my projects, and the table named inquiry created with SQL in another project. User responses’ must be uploaded into the inquiry table by using the MySQL statements. Add the code to upload the information to the inquiry table on the email.php file (the file used to send the emails from the inquiry form). To test that the results were uploaded into the table, use an if…else statement to display to the screen if the results were uploaded or not. Add at least 3 inquiry responses.

NOTE: Be sure the fields names of the inquiry form match the values variable names created to ensure the results are uploaded into the table. If problems with uploading the results, first look at the names of the fields, and order listed.

***This is my inquiry.php:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head> 
<body>
<?php
  $name = $_POST ['name'];
  $address = $_POST ['address'];
  $city = $_POST ['city'];
  $state = $_POST ['state'];
  $zip = $_POST ['zip'];
  $phone = $_POST ['phone'];
  $email = $_POST ['email'];
  $major = $_POST ['major'];
  $year = $_POST ['year'];
  $semester = $_POST ['semester'];
  $to="bgoog@mail.nira.edu, ther691@gmail.com"; //an email is sent to your email account and to 
  $message="To Whom It May Concern, <br>";
  $message.="My information is listed below: <br><br>";
  $message.="Name: $name<br>";
  $message.="Address: $address<br>";
  $message.="City: $city<br>";
  $message.="State: $state<br>";
  $message.="Zip: $zip<br>";
  $message.="Phone: $phone<br>";
  $message.="Email: $email<br>";
  $message.="Major: $major<br><br>";
  $message.="I plan to enter in the $semester of $year. <br>";
  $message.="Please assist me in this matter.<br><br>";
  $message.="Respectfully,<br>";
  $message.="B Good<br>";
  $subject="University - Inquiry Form";//The subject of the email is �University - Inquiry Form�
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: <therock691@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";//the email should like it was sent from the person contacting University
  $response=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
  if($response)
  {
    Echo "Email sent successfully";
  }
  else //
  {
    Echo "Error Occured while sending email";           
  }
  $hostname = "localhost";
  $username = "vde_bgood";
  $password = "s0123456";
  $database = "vde_bgood";
  $table = "inquiry";
  mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to database");
  mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to select db");
  $fields = "id, name, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, major, semester year";
  $values = "'$id', '$name', '$address', '$city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'email', 'major'. 'semester', 'year'";
  $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if($result)
    echo "Thank you for completing the Inquiry Form";
  else
    echo "Sorry, this is not currently working";
?>
<br>
<br>
<a href='inquiry.html'>Go back to contact form</a></body>
</html>
```

.***HTML Document:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function MM_validateForm()
  { //v4.0
    if (document.getElementById)
    {
      var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
      for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3)
      {
        test=args[i+2];
        val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
        if (val)
        {
          nm=val.name;
          if ((val=val.value)!="")
          {
            if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1)
            {
              p=val.indexOf('@');
              if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
            }
            else if (test!='R')
            {
              num = parseFloat(val);
              if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
              if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1)
              {
                p=test.indexOf(':');
                min=test.substring(8,p);
                max=test.substring(p+1);
                if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
              }
            }
          }
          else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n';
        }
      }
      if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
      document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
    }
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="inquiry.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <h2>Nira University Enrollment Form</h2>
    <table width="500" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" form="form1" title="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">Street Address:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">City:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input type="text" name="city" id="city"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">State:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input type="text" name="state" id="state"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">Zip Code:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">Telephone:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" onBlur="MM_validateForm('name','','R','address','','R','city','','R','state','','R','zipcode','','RisNum','phone','','R','email','','RisEmail','major','','R');return document.MM_returnValue"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">Email Address:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><label for="name">Intended Major:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><input type="text" name="major" id="major"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="select">Year:</label></td>
        <td><select name="year" id="year" >
          <option value="">Select Year</option>
          <option value="2014">2014</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
        </select></td>
        <label for="select3"></label>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="select">Semester:</label></td>
        <td width="313"><select name="semester" id="semester"  title="semester">
          <option value="">Select Semester</option>
          <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
          <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
          <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="171"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" onClick="MM_validateForm('name','','R','address','','R','city','','R','state','','R','zip','','RisNum','phone','','R','email','','NisEmail','major','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I genuinely don't understand.  When posting that question, you had to scroll past a preview of your post.  Did it look even *slightly* comprehensible in the form that you left it in?  As you were typing your question, a yellow box headed "**How to Format**" would have appeared to the right.  Did you not read it?  Quite beside the formatting tips, it included a link to [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), which I imagine you didn't read either.  Help us to help you and read those things before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what your supposed to be asking us? However if the problem is coming from your mysql query try this:

```
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO inquiry($fields) VALUES('$values')");
```

Comment: Remove the quotes for `'$table'` and `'$fields'`

Comment: Do they need to be omitted? I've had queries that dont work without the quotes :S

Comment: The quotes for `VALUES('$values')` is OK, but not when it comes to "selecting" tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your $fields and $values variables as you have some inconsistencies. You do not have semester and year separated with a comma in $fields, but you have them separated in the $values. Also, you have a period, not a comma, in between major and semester in $values.

Now, if I'm understanding this right, you have your table with your information in it and now want to populate your form with this information. You're going to have to query your DB and select the information then display it on your form either using variables or an array.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Then you can use as so:

```
$name = $data['name'];
$address = $data['address'];
```

etc.

Then using PHP you can plug these variables where you would like to display them. You can find more info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_select_php.htm.

Hope this helps.